# What is the use of a " by pass "

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pipelines, petroleum-engineering

I'd like a simple explanation of the function of **by pass[image]**,

here is an image of the project am working on and if it can help clarify.

Comment: Please provide more context - where have you seen the term? What project are you working on which might require a bypass? Are you thinking of a valve? The more information you give, the higher the quality of answer that you will receive.

Comment: - The project is a skid count( measurement )  of  Gasoil. and the by pass coutains a valve, therese like two  parallel pipe line with the same  instrument and valves and theres the link ( the by pass  ) between them  that contains a valve  i hope i explained like u asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“By-pass” generally means to take an alternative path or route around something, so could be a village or a valve or a flow meter.

Sometimes meters have a by-pass arrangement with 3 valves so that they can be replaced without stopping the flow.